# Using Low Events with Seg2Cat?

Tags: segments, low-seg2cat, low-events

Trying to build a simple event filtering system with categories (Seg2Cat) and dates. This is my current approach (which does not work):

```
{exp:low_events:entries channel="events_submitted|events_internal" category="{last_segment_category_id}" date="{last_segment}" dynamic="no" parse="inward"}
```

I did manually place a date in the parameter which also did not work.

```
{exp:low_events:entries channel="events_submitted|events_internal" category="{last_segment_category_id}" date="2014-06" dynamic="no" parse="inward"}
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to achieve these results with just the one tag:

- http://URL.dev/events/category/arts/2014-06/ **(Doesn't Work)**
- http://URL.dev/events/category/arts **(Works)**
- http://URL.dev/events/2014-06/ **(Works)**

Is it possible for them to play together? Or should I rethink the approach? Perhaps use Low Search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first URL, you won't get a valid category ID, as `{last_segment_category_id}` points to the last segment: the date. You'd need to get creative with simple conditionals and preload replace vars. Something like this:

```
{if segment_4 != ''}
  {preload_replace:pre_category="{segment_3_category_id}"}
{/if}

{preload_replace:pre_category="{last_segment_category_id}"}

{exp:low_events:entries
  category="{pre_category}"
  date="{last_segment}"
  ...
}
```

Note that this approach only works when using [simple conditionals](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/conditionals.html#simple-conditionals) for the preload replace vars.